# Multiple URLs getting created for single product

Tags: url, url-rewrite, product-urls, redirect-url

I am an SEO executive and pretty new to Magento. I have got a project in which there are multiple URLs for a single product and all URLs have been indexed on Google. Here is an example of URL structure -

https://www.example.com/product-130565

https://www.example.com/main-category/product-130565

https://www.example.com/main-category/sub-category/product-130565

https://www.example.com/main-category/sub-category/sub-category/product-130565

Also, the canonical URL for every URL is different. I want to understand why Magento is creating so many URLs for a single product. Also, I only want to keep the third URL structure as the main URL and all other URLs should either redirect to that URL or is there a way that the other URLs can be removed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration under Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Categories Path for Product URLs > Yes/No

To regenerate product, category URLs you can use below module

https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

To force redirect to the URLs without category path in them you can use the solution given in the below link

https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-prevent-omit-category-path-from-product-url-to-access-the-product-page/